# How to create a vertical line in HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am designing one card just like this.

[image: expected output]

I am wondering how to create a vertical line just below the circle as shown in the picture.

Comment: you can use a gradient or a border-left and offset image to stand on top of it. Do you have anycode to demonstrate what you've done and how it fails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CSS` with `position` to achieve it along with `::before`:

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.circle:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.circle::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -2px;
}
.circle:first-child::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

adjust the height and width of horizontal to be a vertical line using hr tag

Comment: That won't work here.